# jQuery to PHP Array and string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to get the `checked` values into a PHP array so that I am able to loop through the array but I can't seem to convert it to an array.

**jQuery Ajax Posts**

```
checked=28,24
```

**PHP**

```
$checked = $_POST['checked'];

$arr = array($checked);
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 28,24
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**explode**](https://www.php.net/explode) function to convert comma separated string to an array,

```
$arr = explode(",",$checked);
```